# Is there any way to set C++ long type size with 8 bytes (x64)?

Tags: c++, long-integer, sizeof

GCC compiles program using `sizeof(long)=8` and Visual Studio has `sizeof(long)=4`. How to set sizeof(long) to 8 bytes on Winows x64?

Comment: are you able to use `std::int64_t` instead (from [cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)) ?

Comment: if that's so important, just use c99 types

Comment: And FYI, as `sizeof` takes alignment into account, it does not actually indicate binary size or range precisely. For example, if some implementation has `sizeof(long)==8` but `long` overflowed at 2147483647, it would still be standard-compliant behaviour.

Comment: @Borgleader, no beacause it's not my own project and it's huge. So I'm looking the way how to tell compiler that sizeof(long) must be 8 instead of 4.

Comment: You can't. There are standard library functions that take arguments of type `long`. The sizes of `short`, `int`, `long`, and (C++11) `long long` are up to the implementation.

Comment: @DavidHammen, so it is OS-related thing (due to STL), not just the compiler one?

Comment: @AlekDepler No its "implementation defined" afaik if you compiled the code on windows with MinGW its quite possible that long's size could be 8 bytes.

Comment: @AlekDepler: Standard Library not STL, and on Windows the C++ library is unrelated to the OS. (Linux is weird as the C++ library is partially provided by libc which behaves as an OS component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual size of `long` [isn't specified to be an exact number of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be), only the range of values that it must be able to represent. You could however use fixed width integers

```
std::int64_t
```

This, along with other fixed width integer types, are available in [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: Well, I have a huge project, so I'm not able to replace all the code.

Comment: @AlekDepler - You can't do what you want. Write a script that will automate what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common migration issue:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2e7499.aspx.  As said before, the spec doesn't say specifically what size a long is and done platforms will be 4 and sone 8.